# Admob disabled to my application for unknown reason

Tags: admob

this is the second time admob disabled to my app with some unknown violation that i have no idea. i can't figure out the reason, mirroring and framing what?. can someone please guide me what the issue is actually?

Here is my app link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ztronn.fastlitextra

Here is the email i recieved

"Hello,
This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.

Issue ID#: 105626927

Ad serving has been disabled to: com.ztronn.fastlitextra

Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your account for compliance.

Current account status: Active

Violation explanation

As stated in our program policies, we may not show Google ads on pages with little to no value and/or excessive advertising until changes are made. This includes but is not limited to:

Mirroring, framing, scraping or rewriting of content from other sources without adding value
Pages that don’t follow our Webmaster quality guidelines
For more information, please review the following resources:

Policy tips for creating high quality sites (part 1)
Policy tips for creating high quality sites (part 2)
Webmaster quality guidelines
AdSense program policies"

Answer (score 2):

You can't monetize someone else's website (Facebook in the case of your app). 
[Framing content is not allowed.](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)